# studying for clep calculus exam inverse functions and derivates

Tags: calculus, inverse-function

I was taking a practice clep calculus exam I found online and I do not understand how the correct answer was derived.

$f(x) = x^3 + x$.  and $h(x)$ is an inverse function of.  find $h'(2)$???  I know that $f(h(x)) = x$ and if $f'(h(x))h'(x) = 1 $, $h'(x) = 1/f'(h(x))$.  My understanding is that if $f(2) = 10$ then $h(10) = 2$ because they are inverses.  Could somebody help me with my misunderstanding?  I think the correct answer was $1/4$.

Comment: What is "clep calculus" ? This term is surely very familiar in some parts of the world but totally unknown in other parts of the planet...

Answer (score 1):

Sure your understanding is correct but you’re evaluating at the wrong point.

You’re interested in $h’(2)$, so try to evaluate the right hand side $1/f’(h(x))$ at $2$. You need $h(2)$. What value, when plugged into $f$, gives $2$?

More rigorously you should prove that $f$ is invertible, depending on how strict your exam is. But this is easy, since $f$ is strictly increasing and continuous.